# How does the iPhone SDK Core Data system store date types to sqlite?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, date, core-data

I used core data to do this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *m = [self managedObjectContext];
Foo *f = (Foo *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Foo" 
                                                        inManagedObjectContext:m];
f.created_at = [NSDate date];
[m insertObject:f];

NSError *error;
[m save:&error];
```

Where the created_at field is defined as type "Date" in the xcdatamodel.

When I export the sql from the sqlite database it created, created_at is defined as type "timestamp" and the values look like:

290902422.72624

Nine digits before the . and then some fraction.

What is this format?  It's not epoch time and it's not julianday format.

Epoch would be:

1269280338.81213

julianday would be:

2455278.236746875 (notice only 7 digits before the . not 9 like I have)

How can I convert a number like 290902422.72624 to epoch time?  Thanks!

Comment: i when thru all the questions I asked and clicked the check mark next to the good answers.  Is that what u mean?

Comment: yes, and don't forget to continue.  What you need to do is learn the internal format of NSDate, this isn't necessarily Apple (exactly) but the 'owners' of objective-C.  find out this information and you will have your answer.

Comment: in another answer to a question similar to this on SO, the accepted answer was to save the seconds since epoch into the DB instead of an NSDate.  This will be quite useful if you decide to go cross platform.

Comment: You can convert the decimal found in the sqlite to a real date time using http://www.epochconverter.com/coredata

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, note that the Core Data documentation says you should never touch the SQL or values it generates on your own - doing so has the potential to invalidate your model if you make changes to it, and it's difficult to parse in the first place.

That said, what you may be seeing is dates relative to January 1, 2001 in GMT. The documentation for [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) specifies that the single primitive method, `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`, uses that time for its reference. Core Data, in turn, uses the `NSDateAttributeType` to store date types, which is defined to be an NSDate object.

Running your value through a calculator produces:

```
290902422.72624 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25 = 9.21814...
```

which is about the number of years that's elapsed since that reference date.

If you really need to parse that value back into an epoch time you can use the method `initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:` with your SQLite-stored number to get an NSDate, then call `timeIntervalSince1970` to get epoch seconds back (in an NSTimeInterval struct).

Comment: Tim's answer aludes to what I was talking about, change your 'referenceDate' to 'the epoch' and then save your dates that way. When you start saving your data to another platform, life will be much more fun having made this change.

Comment: @kevindtimm: since he's using Core Data, it's gonna be difficult to just arbitrarily convert date storage formats (unless all the NSDate types in his model get switched to NSInteger, or he switches to straight SQLite).

Comment: I would recommend not storing the NSDate, instead store an NSDecimal of the converted value, then convert back when retrieving.  But, only if you're pretty sure the data will need to saved to a central server, where it will be manipulated by other systems.

Comment: thanks guys that's exactly it.  Number of seconds since 1 January 2001, GMT.  The issue here is I'm moving the app over to wax/lua (http://github.com/probablycorey/wax) and no longer using core data.  I'm using the sqlite api directly but need to honor all the existing data on user's phones.

Comment: Good answer, and correct. I went about this the hard way. The dates in my database (526546800) appeared to be about 1/3 of the current epoch time. It's also been about 45 years since 1970, so I assumed they used Jan 1, 2000. I wrote up some code to take the TimeInterval and generate a date based by adding the ticks to the 1/1/2000 ticks. These were close, but not quite close enough. Turns out I was a year off and that Apple provided built in functions for it.

Answer (score 9):

I have run into a related issue of trying to compare Core Data stored date to MySQL stored date in a remote API.  My solution was to use SQLite's date functions to convert the time:

```
SELECT datetime('2001-01-01','+290902422.72624 second');
```

Returns:

```
2010-03-21 22:13:42
```

SQLite assumes the date is in local time and converts it to UTC/GMT.  If you want it to remain in local time, use the local time modifier:

```
SELECT datetime('2001-01-01','+296662599 second','localtime');
```

Returns:

```
2010-03-21 17:13:42
```

This shows the -0500 offset for my local TZ.

Building on that you can use SQLite's strftime function with the format '%s' to get epoch time back:

```
SELECT strftime('%s',datetime('2001-01-01','+290902422.72624 second'));
```

Returns:

```
1269209622
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

Just add 978307200 to the number in core data and you'll get normal timestamp

```
NSString *coreDataTimestamp =@"464615485.832736"; //string of timestamp in coredata
NSTimeInterval timestamp = [coreDataTimestamp doubleValue] + 978307200;
```

Comment: So simple but genius ;-) Thanks for providing the number to add

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in converting dates stored in Core Data to Excel, I came up with this excel forumla, I think its right, it might be off by an hour with the GMT stuff if someone else could confirm that would be cool

=(A1/86400) +35430.042

Answer (score 1):

Here's a website that lets you paste those date numbers and shows you the actual date: http://blog.paddlefish.net/?page_id=90

Or, here's how to read those sqlite dates with ruby:

```
ruby -e "require 'time'; puts Time.parse('2001-01-01 00:00:00 -0000') + 123"
```

Replace `123` with the value in the date column.

Comment: And here's an alias to add to your .bashrc or .zshrc: `alias coredatatime='ruby -e "require \"time\"; puts Time.parse(\"2001-01-01 00:00:00 -0000\") + ARGV[0].to_i"'`. Then you can run `coredatatime 418766400` from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the data directly from the SQLite command line, you would do

select datetime('2001-01-01', dateColumn || 'seconds') from table;
or 
select datetime('2001-01-01', dateColumn || 'seconds', 'localtime') from table;