# Convert number to date time

Tags: ios, date, format

I'm not a programmer. I just needed to get some calendar info out of my iphone backup. I got the data out into a SQL Lite database but the dates are in a number format that I don't understand and I can't find a way to convert them to a format I can read. Can someone show me how to convert the numbers or it might be easier to just convert them for me. The numbers are: 
352425600
353718000
356054400
357350400
358560000
359769600

Thanks

Comment: what are these number? are these `unix timestamps` or what?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if these are in epoch time? try using [this calculator](http://www.convert-unix-time.com) and see if the results look possible to you.

**EDIT:**

nevermind, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2494696/442328) has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

These numbers are stores as a time difference in seconds to the date 1. January 2001 GMT. You can calculate the date by adding the numbers to this date if you treat them as seconds.

If you can use Objective-C you can use the method: `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`

Here is a short loop for calculating the dates:

```
NSArray *dates = @[@352425600, @353718000, @356054400, @357350400, @358560000, @359769600];

    for (NSNumber *timeInterval in dates) {
        NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[timeInterval integerValue]];
        NSLog(@"timeInterval:%@ = date:%@ ", timeInterval, date);
    }
```

And here is the result:

> timeInterval:352425600 = date:2012-03-03 00:00:00 +0000
>   timeInterval:353718000 = date:2012-03-17 23:00:00 +0000
>   timeInterval:356054400 = date:2012-04-14 00:00:00 +0000
>   timeInterval:357350400 = date:2012-04-29 00:00:00 +0000
>   timeInterval:358560000 = date:2012-05-13 00:00:00 +0000
>   timeInterval:359769600 = date:2012-05-27 00:00:00 +0000