# Saving Unix timestamp to NSNumber attribute truncated to single digit 1 in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, unix-timestamp, nsnumber

I am using the following code to assign a unix timestamp to an Integer 32 field called updated. This translates into the auto-generated NSManagedObject subclasses as NSNumber. Here's what I'm doing to set a value.

```
NSNumber *timestamp = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
self.deal.updated = timestamp;
```

However, when I do this, the value that gets saved to updated is just '1', i.e. the single digit 1.

I have also tried this:

```
NSNumber *timestamp = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
self.deal.updated = timestamp;
```

I don't see this as such a complicated task and don't see what I'm missing.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494542/how-does-the-iphone-sdk-core-data-system-store-date-types-to-sqlite) may help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot use a predicate that compares dates in Magical Record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591982/cannot-use-a-predicate-that-compares-dates-in-magical-record) - (You should not call a Core Data attribute "updated" or "deleted".)

Comment: Martin R is right. You have chosen to name your property the same as an existing method on NSManagedObject, - (BOOL)isUpdated. Thus every time you write to your store the value comes back as 1.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR and @ImHuntingWabbits. Changing it from updated to changed worked. I figured it was being set to a similar property but overlooked the `isUpdated` method on `NSManagedObject`